# Retrieve nested dict from Django nested queryset with ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a `models.py` having:

```
class Other(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    other = models.ForeignKey(Other, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

in my rest API i want to retrieve as JsonResponse a json like this:

```
{
    "modelA": {
        "id": "modelA id automatically assigned by django model",
        "name": "my modelA name",
        "other": {
            "id": "other thing id also automatically assigned by django model",
            "name": "other thing name"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the most "pythonic" way to do it?

Comment: show your serialzers, please

Comment: Are you using Django Rest Framework? If not, you should be.

Comment: Yes i am using it

Comment: what do you mean with my serializers? this is just a concectual example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [**nested serialization**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

In your `serializers.py` you should use the serializer for the `Other` model **inside** the one for your `ModelA`.

In `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Other, ModelA


class OtherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Other
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    other = OtherSerializer(read_only=True)
    # The magic happens here.
    # You use your already created OtherSerializer inside the one for ModelA
    # And that will perform nested serialization
    # Which will produce the result that you want

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'other')
        # _________________________^
```

And now you get result like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "my modelA name",
    "other": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "other thing name"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is perfect :)